# In openCV, the inputFrame.rgba().size returns resolution of inputFrame or previewSize of the camera?

Tags: android, opencv, camera, android-camera

Can someone please confirm, in the openCV, the inputFrame.rgba().size() gives the resolution of the inputFrame or the previewSize of the camera?(https://github.com/touchlab-lab/OpenCVAndroidLib/blob/master/opencvandroidlib/src/main/java/org/opencv/android/CameraBridgeViewBase.java#L137)?

I could not find the exact documentation which points out that the rgba().size() returns the maximum resolution for the camera frames!
Because in my code I am changing the previewSize of the cameraFrame and after testing that in my logs the inputFrame.rgba().size() was giving me the changed previewSize and not the resolution I have set using setMaxFrameSize()method(https://github.com/touchlab-lab/OpenCVAndroidLib/blob/master/opencvandroidlib/src/main/java/org/opencv/android/CameraBridgeViewBase.java#L277)

so, here my confusion is with rgba().size as to why it was returning the previewSize of the camera instead of giving me the resolution I have set using the setMaxFrameSize (which should be setting the frame size for OpenCV) and the rgba().size() is supposed to return that resolution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: wanted to know if inputFrame.rgba().size() returns the resolution of the inputFrame or the PreviewSize of the camera?

Comment: [crosspost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159): https://forum.opencv.org/t/in-opencv-the-inputframe-rgba-size-returns-resolution-of-inputframe-or-previewsize-of-the-camera/15420